# linux running a script on a mounted fritz-Box share result in "bad interpreter" in ubuntu 22.04, works on 18.04 (other shares work)

Tags: mount, 22.04, samba, shebang

A script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
or
#!/usr/bin/env python3
...
```

will result in (german):

```
-bash: /mnt/Fritz-USB/FritzUSB/t.sh: /usr/bin/env: Defekter Interpreter: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
```

translated:

```
-bash: /mnt/Fritz-USB/FritzUSB/t.sh: /usr/bin/env: Bad Interpreter: I/O-Error
```

This only happens on a PC running ubuntu 22.04 on a PC running ubuntu 18.04 everything works as expected.
It happens (on 22.04) with every (valid) shebang!

The Mounting options are equal on both systems (except closetimeo=1, which is not available on 18.04).

On ubuntu 22.04 the script will work if started as (or similar):

```
bash /mnt/Fritz-USB/FritzUSB/t.sh
```

If I copy the script onto another mount it will work:

```
cp /mnt/Fritz-USB/FritzUSB/t.sh /mnt/NAS/t.sh

/mnt/NAS/t.sh <-no error
```

I searched the web, but had no luck. maybe someone here has an idea.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Today I tried a "normal" prg on that drive. It turns out, that althougth that this don't run on the (Fritz-Box) cifs mout.
When using a cifs mount of the local atached USB-drive everything works.

So the problem must be the kind the mount reacts.
Because there is no difference between both PCs when using "findmnt -T", I belive it is a problem whith samba on the server side .
I will ask the AVM-support if they know something about.

Comment: Does it also happen if your shebang doesn't use `env`? Do `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/python` fail the same way? What about if you launch the script with `/usr/bin/env bash /mnt/Fritz-USB/FritzUSB/t.sh`? That it works when copied is really weird. In both cases, it is on an external filesystem that is mounted locally, right? So `/usr/bin/env` refers to your local `/usr` dir, correct?

Comment: Yes, it happens whatever vaild path is after the shebang.

Comment: @terdon Yes, it happens whatever vaild path is after the shebang. And Yes I have mounted: a) The Fritz-Box (cifs vers 3.11) and b) USB-HD's. Something interesting is, that xattr doesn't work on a!.

Comment: As far as I understood shebang, it's handeled by a kernel exec-func.  This checks for the "magic" and in case of the shebang it executes the "rest of the line".  Maybe the never kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 makes the difference ?  22.04 uses 6.5.0-26-generic, 18.04 uses 5.4.0-174-generic

Comment: "If I copy the script onto another mount it will work:" - might there be a "automatic" CR+LF feature on the 'non-working' device ? is there a `0D 0A` for the first linefeed in the output of `$ od -t x1z /mnt/Fritz-USB/FritzUSB/t.sh | head -n 10`

Comment: @Hannu No, there is no "line ending problem", hexdump shows only \n & because it works on another PC this should not be the problem

Comment: Well, that was one possible cause. What is clear is: If an unchanged script behaves differently depending on where it is fetched / read from, then the script itself isn't involved.

Comment: To clarify >> if the code that implements shebang:ing reads the first line and gets `... bash<CR><LF>`, removes the expected <LF> but not the <CR>; then you will get the described fault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152323/discussion-between-neiss-gunter-and-hannu).

Comment: The output of `findmnt -T /mnt/Fritz-USB/` and `findmnt -T /mnt/NAS/` might help.